# Sign an app with an existing keystore which does not seem to have a password

Tags: java, apk, keystore

I hope to get some thoughts about the problem I am facing. I have tried multiple solutions, but I am stuck.

We inherited an app from some design studio. They provided the .jks file for signing the app, but not the password. When I call the command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore xx.jks
```

and hit enter when asked for the password (i.e. leave it blank), I get all SHA, alias etc. info for the keystore. Does it mean that it is not protected by the password?

I then tried to sign the .apk with this keystore, but hitting enter doesn't work. It wants a password.

I tried exporting the key using `-exportcert`. First it asked for keystore password. I hit enter. Then it asked for a specific key password, and hitting enter doesn't work.

I am really confused. Is the file password protected or not? If not, what are the steps to use it?

Thanks!

Comment: No, it doesn't mean there is no password. Demand it from the design studio: it is a deliverable along with the application and keystore;  or else generate a new key pair and certificate.

Comment: In JKS format the alias(es), date(s), and certificate(s) are not encrypted, and thus can be read without the password, as you found -- although this data is unverified, as it warns you. The privatekey(s) _are_ encrypted, and without the password cannot be used, which they must be to sign or decrypt. The keytool flag is spelled `-keystore` not `-keys`. However, `-exportcert` does not need the privatekey and should work without password, and does on several of the versions I have installed; on what version does it fail for you?

Comment: But exporting the certificate won't get you anywhere. For signing you need the private key, and for that you need the password.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 out of interest I generated a new key, but running keytool -list without password did not return as much info (i.e. no SHAs or MD5) as for that .jks file, so I thought that was an indication of no password. So the conclusion is that I either need to find the password or create a new app in PlayStore.

Comment: Did you create a new keypair in an existing keystore (file) or a new one, and with which Java? If you create a new file with Java 9 up, by default it creates PKCS12 not JKS, and PKCS12 _does_ encrypt the certs so without password only the aliases (really friendlynames) of privatekeys can be displayed. It also shows a timestamp, but for PKCS12 that's current time not stored time. The `-list` output tells you the format (Keystore type:) if you look closely, at least in 9 up; in 8 from u60 up it has a compatibility hack that sometimes shows wrong type.